# What would be a simplified explanation of Quasiparticles?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quasiparticles

I recently came across a concept in quantum physics called Quasiparticles. They seemed interesting so, I did a little bit of research about them. However, I still don't understand what they are. The Wikipedia page described them as "collective excitations of particles", but I didn't understand what that means.

Could someone please post a simplified explanation of what quasiparticles are? Is there some kind of table like the standard model that organizes them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fundamental particles are excitations of fundamental fields.

A [quasiparticle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiparticle) is an excitation of a *multi-particle system*. The difference between these and elementary particles is that quasiparticles cannot exist outside of a multi-particle system.

A good example are semiconductor [holes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_hole) where many electrons that move in one direction result in the appearance of a positive hole moving in the opposite direction. This positive hole is termed a quasiparticle.

Other examples of quasiparticles are [phonons](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonon), [exitons](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exciton) and [plasmons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasmon).

I’m not sure if there is a table$^1$ of quasiparticles. If there was, it would not be similar to the standard model since quasiparticles are a consequence of a system of particles, unlike the particles of the standard model.

$^1$ Edit: After answering another [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/666469/does-uncertainty-principle-apply-to-holes-gaps-in-matter) regarding quasiparticles, I happened to come across [this article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_quasiparticles)  which lists and describes (with links to) the various known quasiparticles.

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that also electrons in semiconductors are quasiparticles in the single-electron approximation.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano That is an interesting remark. Does it perhaps warrant its own answer?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I really don't have much time these days for a proper answer, but it's essentially the concept expressed in this one. A discussion about this, among many other books, can be found in Cohen, Marvin L.; Louie, Steven G.. _Fundamentals of Condensed Matter Physics_, Cambridge University Press, which gives a list of quasiparticles in solids with their description.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano not only in single-particle approximation - e.g., also in Landau Fermi liquid (e.g., see here https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/648292/247642)