# Why is it that, when light travels in a medium, we say it's made of "quasiparticles"?

Tags: optics, photons, quantum-electrodynamics, refraction, quasiparticles

I get why, in this model, light isn't really "made of" photons, because photons, by definition have zero mass and travel at $c$, whereas these quasiparticles, if I understand correctly, do have mass and can travel at less than $c$.  They're essentially the superposition of photons and the other particles in the medium the photons are interacting with, yes?  So clearly they're different from photons. But why does that make them "quasiparticles" instead of just a different type of particle?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> They're essentially the superposition of photons and the other particles in the medium the photons are interacting with, yes? So clearly they're different from photons.

This is true. In a medium, photons can couple with the excitations (*quasiparticles*) of that medium. For example, a *polariton* is  a superposition of a photon with a quasiparticle such as an exciton.

> But why does that make them "quasiparticles" instead of just a different type of particle?

Quasiparticles are *collective* excitations that exist in a *many body system* (like a solid). They are an emergent phenomenon that, unlike fundamental particles like the photon, cannot exist outside of multiparticle systems. See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/610490/what-would-be-a-simplified-explanation-of-quasiparticles) PSE post.

Comment: "Quasiparticles are collective excitations that exist in a many body system (like a solid). They are an emergent phenomenon that, unlike fundamental particles like the photon, cannot exist outside of multiparticle systems."  But isn't that also true of, e.g. protons and neutrons?  They aren't fundamental particles, but rather arise from the interactions of other particles, yes?  But I've never heard them called quasiparticles instead of particles.

Comment: @MikaylaEckelCifrese You may find helpful Roger Vadim's answer to this question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/604029/is-differentiating-particle-and-quasiparticle-meaningless